# No MaterialLocalizations found in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and struggling to correct below error.  No MaterialLocalizations found. error in code. am I missing a library? or any code ? how can I fix this. appriciate your help on this.

error suggesion >>> To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.

[image]

> createProfile.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' ;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  CreateProfile({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateProfileState createState() => _CreateProfileState();
}

class _CreateProfileState extends State<CreateProfile> {

  bool circular = false;
  PickedFile? _imageFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  final _globalkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _name = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _profession = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _dob = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _title = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _about = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _globalkey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
          children: <Widget>[
            imageProfile(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            nameTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            professionTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            dobField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            titleTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            aboutTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),

            InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                if (_globalkey.currentState!.validate()){
                  print("validated");
                }
              },

              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),

                  child: Center(
                    child: circular
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : Text(
                      "Submit",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget imageProfile() {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
              ? AssetImage("assets/pic.jpg") as ImageProvider
              : FileImage(File(_imageFile!.path)),

        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.camera_alt,
              color: Colors.teal,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Choose Profile photo",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
              onPressed: () {
                takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
              },
              label: Text("Camera", ),
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.image),
              onPressed: () {
                takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
              label: Text("Gallery"),
            ),
          ])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: source,
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile as PickedFile;

    });
  }

  //starting text fields

  Widget nameTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _name,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Name can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Name",
        helperText: "Name can't be empty",
        hintText: "Anne Perera",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget professionTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _profession,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Profession can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Profession",
        helperText: "Profession can't be empty",
        hintText: "Full Stack Developer",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dobField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _dob,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "DOB can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Date Of Birth",
        helperText: "Provide DOB on dd/mm/yyyy",
        hintText: "01/01/2020",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget titleTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _title,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Title can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Title",
        helperText: "It can't be empty",
        hintText: "Flutter Developer",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget aboutTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _about,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "About can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      maxLines: 4,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        labelText: "About",
        helperText: "Write about yourself",
        hintText: "I am Ann Perera",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (USE_EMULATOR) {
    _connectToFirebaseEmulator();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future _connectToFirebaseEmulator() async {
  final fireStorePort = "8080";
  final authPort = 9099;
  final localHost = Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : 'localhost';
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
      host: "$localHost:$fireStorePort",
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false);

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('http://$localHost:', authPort);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(

      home: CreateProfile(key: UniqueKey()),
    
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Color(0xff08c187)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error basically says that to use material widgets in a cupertino app you will have to add this:

```
CupertinoApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
),
```